# Unable to create a file in Java (IOException)

Tags: java, file, date

I am trying to create a directory and csv file inside that directory. The directory is created  but on file creation it gives an exception
Here is my code

```
 File dirName = new File("C:\\Umair\\Trace Bandwidth Statistics");
 if (!dirName.exists())
     dirName.mkdir();
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");  
        File file = new File( dirName + "\\"+ df.format(new Date()) +"_Statistics.csv"); 
        if ( !file.exists() )
            file.createNewFile();
```

I get this exception java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character `:` is not allowed in file names for Windows, so you cannot add the `df.format(new Date())` part to the file name

Here are the file name rules for Windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Because Microsoft says so :-) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. My guess would be that it has something to do with the fact that `:` is used in drive letters.

Comment: http://jackguide.com/the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect/ take a look here

Answer (score 1):

The characters like `\/:*?"<>|` are not allowed for a file name in Windows. Strip those characters, and the file will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Since its a windows File system, I assume its rejecting your filename based on its inclusion of illegal characters.  e.g. ":"

(Also, as an aside, I use mkdirs() rather than mkdir(), for safety.  Also get used to using File.separator instead of \ in case you need to move your application to env's that use / instead of )

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the following are reserved chars and cannot be used in a file name:

- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- - (asterisk)

As you are using `:` as part of the date appending to the file name hence the file is not getting created.